# Creating a custom .svc handler for WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7

I am hosting a wcf service in IIS 7. I was curious if it would be possible to create my own .svc HttpHandler mapping and class to handle service requests.

For example, if I was to intercept any requests to files that ended with an extension of ".foo" I could add this to my web.config

```
<handlers>
     <add name="*.foo_**" path="*.foo" verb="*" type="MyServer.FooHttpHandler" />      
</handlers>
```

And I could have a class in my default root that did the following

```
public class FooHandler: IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // do stuff, validate?

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("filename={0}", url));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "fooMimeType");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(url);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this with wcf .svc requests? I'm not sure if it'd be the exact same thing or not, since I'm not necessary serving a file to respond with, I want to intercept and proxy the response.

Or is a better way to implement a service behavior that does my required pre-service logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? Not sure if you can replace the existing *.svc http handler - but what you can do much more easily is create your own custom `ServiceHostFactory` for the WCF service. You basically add one attribute your *.svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="YourNamespace.YourService" 
    Factory="YourNamespace2.YourServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Using this, IIS will now instantiate your own `YourServiceHostFactory` and ask you to create an instance of the `YourService` class. Maybe you can hook into the flow here and do what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ASP.NET Routing and an IRouteHandler that returns your own IHttpHandler implementation as well if you really want to as well 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.gethttphandler.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

I've done this in the past when setting up WCF Data Services and I don't see why it can't work here as well.